# This ODE has one general solutions or two solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The ODE
$$2xy''-y'+\frac{1}{y'}=0$$
is a second order ODE , so it must have one general solution containing 2 constants  .
I solved it by reduction of order as following but I have 2 general solutions each contains 2 constants , since I have positive and negative square root . I would like to know , do they represent one general solution since the sign can be included into the constant ? or do they represent as I said before 2 general solutions ?

Here is my solution :

let v=y' , v'=y''
$$2xv'=v-\frac{1}{v}$$
$$v^2-1=cx$$
$$v=\pm\sqrt{cx+1}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\pm\sqrt{cx+1}$$
$$y=\pm\frac{2}{3c}(cx+1)^{3/2}+k$$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\pm\sqrt{cx+1}$ is a valid equation, but it is **not** a valid expression for a function, and therefore not integrable. Read $\pm$ as plus *or*  minus, not plus *and* minus. The derivative must be equal to either the positive **or** negative portion. You would solve this by using your initial conditions of the ODE.

Answer (score 1):

You have not 2 general solutions each contains 2 constants. You have two sub-sets of solutions. Each one in not a general solution. The general solution is the gather of the two.

Another expression of the general solution is on the form of an implicit equation :
$$4(cx+1)^3-9c^2(y-k)^2=0 \qquad\text{There is no }\pm\text{ in it.}$$ $$ $$

The situation is comparable to this :

A circle which equation is :
$$x^2+y^2=r^2$$
is equivalently described by :
$$y(x)=\pm\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$$
which means the gather of to semicircles $\quad y(x)=\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\quad $ and $\quad y(x)=-\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$
$$ $$
In fact this is not yet all the solutions of the PDE.

When you wrote :

" $2xy″−y′+1y′=0$ is a second order ODE , so it must have one general solution containing 2 constants"

you are thinking of a linear ODE. But the ODE is not linear. So, the above statment is false.

The solutions of the ODE are not only 
$$\quad y=\pm\frac{2}{3c}(cx+1)^{3/2}+k\quad $$ 
but also 
$$y(x)=\pm x+k$$
This can be seen directly from the ODE in case of $y''=0$ or alternatively in looking for the envelope of the family of curves $4(cx+1)^3-9c^2(y-k)^2=0$ which differentiation wrt $c$ leads to $c=2/x$ and then $x^2-(y-k)^2=0$.